# Table of content for Rpresentation

Tags: r, shiny, knitr, r-markdown

I am creating a presentation with Rstudio using knitr and I want to use the types of the slides to generate a table of contents slide in the beginning. So if I have the following code:

```
Some fun lecture
========================================================
author: some guy
date: in the future

Table of content slide
========================================================
Here I want the table of content based on the following slide types

Some stuff 1
========================================================
type:section
Some very important stuff

More detail on stuff 1
========================================================
type:subsection
Did not get enough of stuff 1!? Here is more :D

Stuff 2
========================================================
type:section
There are other kinds of stuff?

Prompt slide
========================================================
type:prompt
Do not display prompt or alert types in TOC
```

So basically I want a table of content slide after the title slide looking something like:

- Some stuff 1

  - More detail on stuff 1
- Stuff 2

Is this available by default or do I need some extra CSS style in the beginning to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To generate a table of contents, include a document header with the option "toc:true" at the beginning of the document. Level 1 headings are indicated by #, level 2 headings by ##, and so on. Below is an example . The "prompt" option is only relevant for R code chunks. R code chunks are not listed in the table of contents.

This will, however, only produce a html document. If you want a Latex-like presentation with individual slides, you can replace `html_document` with `beamer_presentation`. In the beamer presentation, only level 1 headings are listed in the table of contents.

````
---
title: "Sample Document"
author: "Author"
output:
  html_document:
    toc: true
---

# Some stuff 1
Some very important stuff

## More detail on stuff 1
Did not get enough of stuff 1!? Here is more :D

# Stuff 2
There are other kinds of stuff?

```{r, prompt=TRUE}
summary(iris[, "Sepal.Length"])
```
````

For more info on Beamer presentations in Rmarkdown, see http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/beamer_presentation_format.html. A similar question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23957278/how-to-add-table-of-contents-in-rmarkdown).