# Table of content in beamer generated with R markdown/knitr

Tags: r, markdown, rstudio, knitr

In line with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23957278/2205465) question, I have problems generating table of contents with a beamer class document, which I have made in RStudio with R markdown and knitr.

My YAML header looks like this:

```
---
params:
  x: !r x
author: "Author"
date: "Januar 2016"
graphics: yes
fontsize: 10pt
output:
  beamer_presentation:
    includes:
      in_header: in_header.tex
    keep_tex: yes
    latex_engine: xelatex
    slide_level: 1
    template: body.tex
    toc: true
classoption: aspectratio=169
---
```

I use the default beamer template in body.tex found [here](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-templates/blob/master/default.beamer) (I needed to make som adjustsments to the title page, so that's why I have referred to it explicitly).

I render the document with

```
render(input = "file_name.Rmd",
         params = list(x = i),
         output_file = "file_name.beamer.pdf"
         )
```

However, only a blank page shows up in the pdf generated and no TOC. I have tried to run render several times.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A table of contents lists *sections*, not individual pages. But you have no section in your document: since you used `slide_level: 1`, all level 1 titles are slides.

If you add sections to your document, you will get a toc. That would be the proper use. Something like:

```
---
output:
  beamer_presentation:
    slide_level: 2
    toc: true
---

# Section 1

## Slide 1
Slide content

## Slide 2
Slide content
```

If you really want to get a list of individuals slides as a table of content, there might be a way to do that with `\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{...}` in your preamble, but [tex.stackexchange.com](http://tex.stackexchange.com) is better suited for this question.