# Rmarkdown Beamer 16:9 aspect ratio

Tags: latex, rstudio, r-markdown, beamer

How to set the aspect ratio of beamer slides created using `Rmarkdown` in Rstudio to 16:9? It does not seem to be a standard option. I tried changing the `\documentclass{}` options using a `header.tex` insert but this was not successful.

Comment: Have you read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34814100/table-of-content-in-beamer-generated-with-r-markdown-knitr

Comment: No I did not. Thanks for pointing me to it! After reading it, I tried classoption: aspectratio=169. This did not result in an error but also not in a 16:9 presentation

Comment: Show us your YAML header.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Put the option in double quotes:

```
output: 
  beamer_presentation:
classoption: "aspectratio=169"
```

Notice that `classoption` keyword is at the same level with `output`.

- pandoc 1.19
- texlive 2015
- knitr 1.17
- rmarkdown 1.6