# Adding a table of contents in an r notebook

Tags: r, rnotebook

There doesn't seem to be a problem when I add a table of contents to an r markdown file but nothing happens when I add this to an r notebook:

```
output: 
   html_document:
   html_notebook:
      toc: true
      depth: 3
      theme: united
```

Is it possible to add a table of contents to an R notebook or do I have to make this into a markdown file too?

Answer (score 3):

I had to format it like this in the end:

```
output: 
  html_notebook:
    theme: united
    toc: yes
```

Answer (score 2):

Try formatting like this:

```
title: "Title"
output:
  html_notebook:
    theme: united
    toc: yes
```

Comment: Also, looks like a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23957278/how-to-add-table-of-contents-in-rmarkdown)

Comment: I saw that question but it is about R markdown, which I have had no problem adding a TOC to, instead of R notebooks.

Answer (score 1):

`html_document:` is not followed by any attributes that’s why the `html_notebook` settings are not being executed properly.

Either remove `html_document:` or specify some attributes underneath it.

Comment: Stating `toc: yes` for `html_document` before `html_notebook:` can override your theming.