# Table of Contents for R_Notebook

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I'm trying to generate a html with a table of contents using the YAML header in **R Notebook**. I've found answers to this question (e.g., [Adding a table of contents in an r notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45825882/adding-a-table-of-contents-in-an-r-notebook)) but the code still isn't generating a toc on the html. I have specified headers using #, ##, etc

```
---
title: "CMiller_SentencesTask_Analysis"
author: "Chantal Miller"
output:
  html_notebook:
    toc: yes
---
```

Comment: Seems to work here.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved! I forgot to place a space between the heading names and the hashtag e.g.,

## Heading 1

rather than

#Heading 1