# Rmarkdown beamer table of contents slides, plus grayed out for not current sections

Tags: r, latex, markdown, r-markdown, beamer

I want to insert a table of contents slide toward the beginning , but not the very beginning.

Additionally, I want it so that as each new section arrives, the table of contents slide is repeated, but with this time everything grayed out except the current section, for example see image.

([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23957278/how-to-add-table-of-contents-in-rmarkdown) other answer will not work because toc: true just puts one table of contents at the very beginning)

Some answers KIND of exist in Latex (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26712/how-to-make-outline-frame-in-beamer)), but I don't know how to operationalize these within markdown.  More generally, I have trouble integrating  native beamer latex into rmarkdown, so if someone can show me how to do that, esp with this example, that is helpful.

[image]

Beamer preamble:

```
output:
  beamer_presentation:
    fig_width: 7
    fig_height: 6
    fig_caption: false
#    keep_tex: true
#    toc: true
    slide_level: 3
    includes:
      in_header: ~/Google Drive/.../.../../latexbeamertheme.r
header-includes:
- \AtBeginSection[]{\begin{frame}\tableofcontents[currentsection]\end{frame}}
```

Comment: @Kristofersen it's not a duplicate, that method can be solved using toc, which i am not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve this problem via `header-includes`; that's how you add things to what we'd call the preamble in a LaTeX document. Here's example code that generates a presentation with what I think you want to accomplish:

```
---
title: "Example"
output: beamer_presentation
header-includes:
- \AtBeginSection[]{\begin{frame}\tableofcontents[currentsection]\end{frame}}
---

# Test Section One

----

Test

----

Test


# Test Section Two

----

Test

----

Test
```

## Edit:

If you want or need to do this manually, rather than using the `header-includes` approach, you can:

```
---
title: "Example"
output: beamer_presentation
---

# Test Section One

----

\tableofcontents[currentsection]

----

Test

----

Test


# Test Section Two

----

\tableofcontents[currentsection]

----

Test

----

Test
```

Comment: Now this doesn't seem to work when I add it to my full doc, which already has a latex preamble.  Could it be the case it's getting overridden?

Comment: (See question for my preamble bit for beamer markdown)

Comment: Is it possible to post/comment your whole code (or at least all the code before the presentation content and code for a couple of slides, or a dummy slide or two)?

Comment: Also, does putting the example code I posted in its own separate document Knit OK for you?

Comment: Do you want me to show you the contents of my latex preamble file?  Maybe that is doing it?

Comment: I would suggest adding the `\AtBeginSection[]{\begin{frame}\tableofcontents[currentsection]\end{frame}}` as a new line in the file you've included via `in_header`; let me know if that works.

Comment: I might be spacing it wrong, but I get this error: Error in yaml::yaml.load(enc2utf8(string), ...) : 
  Reader error: control characters are not allowed: #C at 345
Calls: <Anonymous> ... yaml_load_utf8 -> mark_utf8 -> <Anonymous> -> .Call
Execution halted

Comment: You may need to de-indent the line `header-includes`

Comment: I thought you said to get rid of it and just put it under "in header"

Comment: Yeah, fair enough; I was just looking back over your posted preamble code and noticed it was indented there when it should not have been. I forgot you would have removed that line.

Comment: Based on some things I found by searching for related terms to your error, especially [link](https://github.com/rstudio/packrat/issues/382) and [link](https://github.com/rstudio/packrat/issues/382) (see the last comment), this may be an issue related to RStudio not reading the file encoding correctly, or the inclusion of a non-latin character without UTF-8 encoding, or some combination of those issues. Are there any such characters in your document? What is the encoding your files are saved with? Does pasting the content of your .Rmd and .r files into new files allow you to Knit the document?

Comment: is there not just a way to do this manually after each section change?  I do have latex characters in my document.  I am outputting the beamer presentation to a pdf

Comment: Yes, there is. I've updated my answer to include it.

Comment: Oh wow, ok this is great, thank you!  I think the four dashes to indicate a new frame was precisely what I was looking for.   As a side note, it seems to show all subsections and clutters up the table of contents, do you know the command to just show the main headers?

Comment: Actually, I figured it out, you separate parameters with a comma, and this works: \tableofcontents[currentsection,hideallsubsections]