# left menu' with Rmarkdown websites

Tags: r, r-markdown

i would like to make document exactly like this https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/rmarkdown_websites.html
Really like that kind of left menu', do you maybe know how to make it with Rmarkdown itself? i can just find anchor links and the possibility to create a website with the menu' on the bar on top according to their example. It would be nice to have the same menu' as in this document.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add table of contents in Rmarkdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23957278/how-to-add-table-of-contents-in-rmarkdown)

Comment: thank you, i was searching for something on the style of the link i posted. But this solution is nice as well!

Comment: No problem! You'll find more detail on table of contents from here as well: https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/html_document_format.html#floating_toc.

Comment: amazing thanks: that was exactly what i wanted: toc_float: true