# Rmarkdown Table of Contents on page 2 and cross referencing

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, pdfdocument

I would like my pdf output to satisfy 3 conditions:

1. Title page on page 1
2. Table of contents on page 2
3. Cross reference figures and tables.

I am able to do 1 and 2 with `pdf_document` but as explained [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/cross-ref.html), `pdf_document2` is required for 3.

How can I build a pdf document that can satisfy these 3 conditions? I would like to avoid setting my document class to a report if possible.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50330496/7153771) answer is the closest I have found.

Sample code:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    number_sections: true
---

\newpage
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\newpage


```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

Figure (...) below is a 

```{r pressure}
plot(pressure)
```
````

Comment: So you don't want to use `pdf_document2`?

Comment: @Quinten I've edited the title to clarify the unimportance of output type. Either `pdf_document` or `pdf_document2` will be fine as long as the 3 conditions are met.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add \ref{}

````
## R Markdown

Figure (\ref{fig:pressure}) below is a ...

```{r pressure}
plot(pressure)
```
````