# how to add title to table of contents in Rmarkdown

Tags: r-markdown

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGCeB.png)
how to add title to table of contents in Rmarkdown and output like this image:

please give me answer, this is my homework and i'm beginer of Rmarkdown. thank you so much. have a good day!!!!!

Comment: Learn from this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-add-table-of-contents-in-rmarkdown/

Comment: Also this should help your homework: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23957278/how-to-add-table-of-contents-in-rmarkdown